# magento migrate: settings failing

Tags: magento-2.1, data-migration

Working on localhost on a Mac (OS = Sierra) 
Have installed `Magento 2.1.7`
Have install `Data Migration Tools 2.1.7`
Have set up `config.xml` as per instructions,
Attempting to migrate settings from `1.9.2.1 to 2.1.7`

**Error Message**

> [Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException]     EntityRef:
>   expecting ';'                               Line: 101

I am not sure which file this is referring to...?

Comment: You can check more info in var/log/migration folder

Answer (score 1):

Summary of 3 issues I hit while using `magento migrate:settings` & my fixes:

1) my database user password was too complex with non alpha-numeric chars caused a fake syntax error on line 101 of config.xml. 
FIX: use a basic alpha-numeric db user password.

2) "Undefined offset" Error on line 106 in AbstractMigrateCommand.php . 
FIX: commented out lines 105, 106, 107, 109 leaving just `$this->logManager->process();`

3) "A non well formed numeric value encountered" line 232 in AbstractResource.php: 
FIX: changed line 225 from `$memoryLimit = trim($memoryLimit);` to `$memoryLimit = 1024;`